# Add Rounded Corners to image in Elementor Text Editor

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

This is driving me mad. I have an image within a text box on a straightforward elementor page. It is sitting nicely in the "Text Editor Widget" and I want to add rounded corners to it.

I have created a CSS class in "Site Settings/Custom CSS" and then assigned the image to that class within the image editor in the text editor. .AZ-rounded-image { border-radius: 15px; } And nothing happens... Can anyone help -- I have wasted there hours on this ... Many thanks in advance Andy

Comment: have you tried changing the css rule to `.AZ-rounded-image img{ border-radius: 15px; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `overflow` to `hidden`, like shown below? By default `overflow` is `visible` hence if the content of `.AZ-rounded-image` is larger it will overflow making the `border-radius` invisible.

```
.AZ-rounded-image { 
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the time you took to reply.

I tried that but it didn't wrk.

But I have solved it: my CSS class was being over-written by something within elementor.

So I added "!important" to the line and all is well!  It works and sanity has returned.

Many thanks

Andy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the line in question is border-radius: 15px;